# How to retrieve real value from html symbols in jsx?

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx, special-characters

I have a simple HTML form with an input of `name="comment"`. I am displaying the result with jsx in a react app using `{formData.comment}`. 
The form and result works fine for normal input like `hello world` but for special character input like 
 `that's` output is `that&#x27;s`.
How to get the value as it is sent to the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to replace the character entities. I don't think there's a native way of doing this in Javascript (if so someone please comment it or add an answer with it). But luckily doing it manually is quite simple:

```
// The list of characters to escape
const htmlEscapes = {
  '&': '&amp;',
  '<': '&lt;',
  '>': '&gt;',
  '"': '&quot;',
  "'": '&#x27;',
  '/': '&#x2F;'
};

// Sample string with an apostrophe character entity in it
let str = 'that&#x27;s';

// Loop over the entities to escape and regex them out
Object
  .entries(htmlEscapes)
  .forEach(([plain, hexCode]) => str = str.replace(new RegExp(hexCode, 'g'), plain));

// String is now sanitized
console.log(str);
```

This is just one sample way of doing it, point being you'd have to process the string to replace them

Comment: Native way of doing it would have been nice. But this is working just fine. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

How did you get your data ?

```
function Form() {
  const [comm,setComm] = React.useState()

  const submitHandler = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const data = new FormData(e.target)
    setComm(data.get('comment'))
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
      <input
        name="comment"
        type="text"
      />
      <button type="submit">
        submit
      </button>
      <div>Result : {comm}</div>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Comment: I am using class component. But it's pretty much like your code only. Does functional component takes care of the problem itself?

Comment: Functional components have the same way of rendering. The difference is more the scope of the function. But on this exemple a class component should have the same result :-/

Comment: Yeah. result should be the same. Anyway thanks for the advice. I will try using functional component too and see if it works.